# How to set link is Mage::getBaseUrl for breadcrumbs in layout?

Tags: magento, url

#### From layout, how can I set `crumbInfo/link` is Mage::getBaseUrl() for breadcrumbs?

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <contacts_index_index translate="label">
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Accueil</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Accueil</label>
                    <title>Accueil</title>
                    <link>/</link><!--How can I set Mage::getBaseUrl() here-->
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Contactez-nous</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Contactez-nous</label>
                    <title>Contactez-nous</title>
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For argument nodes in layout XML, you can specify a helper and method; the return value of the method will be passed as the argument.

In your xml above, you can pass `<link helper="class_group/classname/method" />` and create a helper to return the URL value that you like.

Comment: @benmarks - I was surprised this does not appear to work, at least under 1.9. It appears that a helper can be invoked for the entire crumbInfo node (i.e. `<crumbInfo helper="..."/>`), but not values within it as indicated in your answer.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to use URL in layout XML then Try this that will work everywhere :

```
<link>{{baseUrl}}</link>
<link>{{baseSecureUrl}}</link>
<!-- Using Identifier -->
<link>{{baseUrl}}some-identifier</link>
```

Basically when `Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update` constructor call that will parse **`{{baseUrl}}`** and **`{{baseSecureUrl}}`**.

These will work for all layout file.

Comment: This answer should be marked as the best answer for that question ever! :) You're the man. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The only working method to do this seems to be using `<link>{{baseUrl}}</link>` as you can read in this [link](http://www.dmertl.com/blog/?p=49).

Comment: Kindly enter the code you want to answer as the solution.